# How to write Backticks in Intellij IDEA 2019.2?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard, backticks

I just updated Intellij to 2019.2 and I'm not able to use the "AltGr + ` " anymore to write backticks. I can copy paste and use it, it has the same effects, but I'm unable to type it.

Is it a bug ? Or should I configure something ?

I'm using a French Keyboard where backtick are "AltGr + 7".

Note : ~ seems not to work either.

Comment: This is indeed a bug, it will be fixed in a 2019.2.x update: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215309

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that I've found 5s after posting the question :

You can use Ctrl+Alt instead of AltGr. Found here : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215309

Still, this does not answer the question so waiting for a more accurate/working solution.